# Sorting array based on matched and unmatched values using es6

Tags: javascript, angular, sorting, ecmascript-6, filter

This could be a simple one, but I have been stuck for a while to make it simple.

I have two arrays, one is tabs and another one is repositories.

I'm trying to sort the tabs array based on the list of repositories. If repository name match with the tabs, it should be sorted first (based on original array) and unmatched tabs name should be sorted last (as per the original array).

But, I tried below and cannot able to sort based on above condition.

Can someone help on this ?

I would expect the solution to be used in angular 8.

```js
var tabs = ["Primary", "302-15", "152-88", "MEVCP"];  
// Imagine it's a tab names

var repositories = [
  {
    "repositoryGuid": "",
    "name": "Git Test 4",
    "description": "Git Description",
    "provider": "",
    "url": "",
    "modified": "2019-11-18T02:39:17.333",
    "modifiedBy": ""
  },
  {
    "repositoryGuid": "123",
    "name": "Primary",
    "description": "ITP Primary SQL Database",
    "provider": "",
    "url": "",
    "modified": "2019-06-06T00:00:00",
    "modifiedBy": ""
  },
  {
    "repositoryGuid": "456",
    "name": "MEVCP",
    "description": "GIT test repository",
    "provider": "",
    "url": "",
    "modified": "2019-09-30T16:01:47.17",
    "modifiedBy": ""
  },
  {
    "repositoryGuid": "679",
    "name": "GIT Test",
    "description": "GIT test repository",
    "provider": "",
    "url": "",
    "modified": "2019-11-15T21:26:22.27",
    "modifiedBy": ""
  },
  {
    "repositoryGuid": "591",
    "name": "ME-Cored-Convergence",
    "description": "ME-Core-Convergence",
    "provider": "",
    "url": "",
    "modified": "2019-09-30T15:38:46",
    "modifiedBy": ""
  }
];

const intersection = repositories.filter(element => tabs.includes(element.name));
console.log(intersection); // Getting matched values from tabs array

tabs.sort(function (a, b) {
  return intersection.indexOf(a.name) - intersection.indexOf(b.name);
});

console.log("after sorting", tabs);
```

Expected Output should be

```
["Primary", "MEVCP", "302-15", "152-88"]
```

PS: All other unmatched values should be sorted in the same level as original array.

Comment: "*I would expect the solution to be used in angular 8.*" this is a pure JS problem, or am I missing something?

Comment: Can be simpler like es6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate throught `repositories` and `splice` tabs every time there is a match and then concatenate result with remaining items:

```js
var tabs = ["Primary", "302-15", "152-88", "MEVCP"];  
// Imagine it's a tab names

var repositories = [
  {
    "repositoryGuid": "",
    "name": "Git Test 4",
    "description": "Git Description",
    "provider": "",
    "url": "",
    "modified": "2019-11-18T02:39:17.333",
    "modifiedBy": ""
  },
  {
    "repositoryGuid": "123",
    "name": "Primary",
    "description": "ITP Primary SQL Database",
    "provider": "",
    "url": "",
    "modified": "2019-06-06T00:00:00",
    "modifiedBy": ""
  },
  {
    "repositoryGuid": "456",
    "name": "MEVCP",
    "description": "GIT test repository",
    "provider": "",
    "url": "",
    "modified": "2019-09-30T16:01:47.17",
    "modifiedBy": ""
  },
  {
    "repositoryGuid": "679",
    "name": "GIT Test",
    "description": "GIT test repository",
    "provider": "",
    "url": "",
    "modified": "2019-11-15T21:26:22.27",
    "modifiedBy": ""
  },
  {
    "repositoryGuid": "591",
    "name": "ME-Cored-Convergence",
    "description": "ME-Core-Convergence",
    "provider": "",
    "url": "",
    "modified": "2019-09-30T15:38:46",
    "modifiedBy": ""
  }
];

let result = [];

for(let rep of repositories) {
   let index = tabs.indexOf(rep.name);
   if(index !== -1) {
      result.push(tabs[index]);
      tabs.splice(index, 1);
   }
}

result = [...result, ...tabs];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with `O(n)` complexity if you

1. Get a Set of all the existing repositories first to save you the lookup later.
2. Since you also need to sort based on initial position in the array, then you need to keep that.

   - You can get a Map of all the sorting criteria for each of the array
3. Finally sort `tabs` based on existence in `repositories`

   - if one tab exists, the other doesn't - put the existing one higher
   - if both tabs exist or don't exist - sort based on position

Here is how this can look like:

```js
var tabs = ["Primary", "302-15", "152-88", "MEVCP"];  
// Imagine it's a tab names

var repositories = [ { "repositoryGuid": "", "name": "Git Test 4", "description": "Git Description", "provider": "", "url": "", "modified": "2019-11-18T02:39:17.333", "modifiedBy": "" }, { "repositoryGuid": "123", "name": "Primary", "description": "ITP Primary SQL Database", "provider": "", "url": "", "modified": "2019-06-06T00:00:00", "modifiedBy": "" }, { "repositoryGuid": "456", "name": "MEVCP", "description": "GIT test repository", "provider": "", "url": "", "modified": "2019-09-30T16:01:47.17", "modifiedBy": "" }, { "repositoryGuid": "679", "name": "GIT Test", "description": "GIT test repository", "provider": "", "url": "", "modified": "2019-11-15T21:26:22.27", "modifiedBy": "" }, { "repositoryGuid": "591", "name": "ME-Cored-Convergence", "description": "ME-Core-Convergence", "provider": "", "url": "", "modified": "2019-09-30T15:38:46", "modifiedBy": "" } ]; 

//1. create set
const set = new Set(repositories.map(repo => repo.name));

//2. create map with sorting data
const map = new Map(tabs
  .map((tab, index) => [
    tab,
    { index, exists: set.has(tab) }
  ]
))

//3. sort
tabs.sort((a, b) => {
  const tabA = map.get(a);
  const tabB = map.get(b);
  
  return (tabB.exists - tabA.exists) || 
    (tabA.index - tabB.index)
});

console.log("after sorting", tabs);
```

An alternative is to do the equivalent as chained operation

1. Get the set
2. Enrich the array with the data relevant for sorting
3. Sort
4. Extract the data for the original array

Here is the implementation:

```js
var tabs = ["Primary", "302-15", "152-88", "MEVCP"];  
// Imagine it's a tab names

var repositories = [ { "repositoryGuid": "", "name": "Git Test 4", "description": "Git Description", "provider": "", "url": "", "modified": "2019-11-18T02:39:17.333", "modifiedBy": "" }, { "repositoryGuid": "123", "name": "Primary", "description": "ITP Primary SQL Database", "provider": "", "url": "", "modified": "2019-06-06T00:00:00", "modifiedBy": "" }, { "repositoryGuid": "456", "name": "MEVCP", "description": "GIT test repository", "provider": "", "url": "", "modified": "2019-09-30T16:01:47.17", "modifiedBy": "" }, { "repositoryGuid": "679", "name": "GIT Test", "description": "GIT test repository", "provider": "", "url": "", "modified": "2019-11-15T21:26:22.27", "modifiedBy": "" }, { "repositoryGuid": "591", "name": "ME-Cored-Convergence", "description": "ME-Core-Convergence", "provider": "", "url": "", "modified": "2019-09-30T15:38:46", "modifiedBy": "" } ]; 

//1. create the set
const set = new Set(repositories.map(repo => repo.name));

const sorted = tabs
  .map((tab, index) => ({ //2. enrich
    tab, 
    index, 
    exists: set.has(tab)
  }))
  .sort((a, b) => (b.exists - a.exists) || (a.index - b.index)) //3. sort
  .map(({tab}) => tab); //4. extract

console.log("after sorting", sorted);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer